# PyQT5 doesn't work on docker ImportError: libsmime3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I have a Dockerfile with PyQT installed like below

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN adduser --quiet --disabled-password qtuser && usermod -a -G audio qtuser
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install alsa -y \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pyqt5 \
    && apt-get install python3-pip -y && \
    pip3 install pyqtwebengine
WORKDIR /htmltopdf
```

I built my image like this `docker build -t html-to-pdf .`

Then I ran my image like this `docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/htmltopdf -u qtuser -it html-to-pdf python3 htmlToPdfnew.py --url https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_register_form.asp`

But I'm getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "htmlToPdfnew.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
ImportError: libsmime3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I do NOT get that error in my PC.

below is my python code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageLayout, QPageSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import argparse


def main():
    url = ''
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Just an example", formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("--url", help="Type url")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    config = vars(args)
    url = config['url']


    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    loader.setZoomFactor(1)
    layout = QPageLayout()
    layout.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4Extra))
    layout.setOrientation(QPageLayout.Portrait)
    loader.load(QUrl(url))
    loader.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(lambda *args: QApplication.exit())

    def emit_pdf(finished):
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: loader.page().printToPdf("test.pdf", pageLayout=layout))

    loader.loadFinished.connect(emit_pdf)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so how do I resolve below error ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "htmlToPdfnew.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
ImportError: libsmime3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install libnss3 in the Docker image.

Adding `apt-get install libnss3` to your installation commands in the `Dockerfile` should do the trick.